# Tabs via Wordpress Shortcodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having trouble adding a class to some jQuery tabs I'm currently using in Wordpres. The following code created a shortcode that creates the tabs. My question is how do I add a class to the tab that's being showed, the 'active' tab. I want to be able to add this class to the tab being displayed so I can style it up with CSS. Here's the code that I'm currently using, it works find but It adds no classes to the active tab:

```
add_shortcode( 'tabgroup', 'jqtools_tab_group' );
function jqtools_tab_group( $atts, $content ){
$GLOBALS['tab_count'] = 0;

do_shortcode( $content );

if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'] ) ){
foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'] as $tab ){
$tabs[] = '<li><a class="" href="#">'.$tab['title'].'</a></li>';
$panes[] = '<div class="pane"><h3>'.$tab['title'].'</h3>'.$tab['content'].'</div>';
}
$return = "\n".'<!-- the tabs --><ul class="tabs">'.implode( "\n", $tabs ).'</ul>'."\n".'<!-- tab "panes" --><div class="panes">'.implode( "\n", $panes ).'</div>'."\n";
}
return $return;
}

add_shortcode( 'tab', 'jqtools_tab' );
function jqtools_tab( $atts, $content ){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'title' => 'Tab %d'
), $atts));

$x = $GLOBALS['tab_count'];
$GLOBALS['tabs'][$x] = array( 'title' => sprintf( $title, $GLOBALS['tab_count'] ), 'content' =>      $content );

$GLOBALS['tab_count']++;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much better if you use jquery/javascript to add the class.

if you are sure of which tab is active on page load you can dynamically add the active class via jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// That is if the first tab is the default active tab.
// Assuming the li tag is what you want to apply the 'active' class on
$('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');

// Manipulate Class on click event.
// Assuming the li tag is what you want to apply the 'active' class on


$('ul.li a').click(function() {
// Remove any 'active' class previously added.
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

// Add 'active' class to the selected tab.
$(this).parent().addClass('active');

});
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked! Made some minor tweaks to your code but I don't think I would of done it without it, thanks a lot man! Cheers